# Subtraction of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two inequalities:
$$k_1 \leq a$$ 
$$k_2 \leq b$$

where $k_1,k_2,a,b$ are all positive numbers

I know that that summation of them can be written as:
$$k_1+k_2 \leq a+b$$

But I want to find $$k_1-k_2 \leq ?$$ or $$? \leq k_1-k_2$$

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @draks: what should be instead of question mark?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @draks: If i knew i would not ask

Comment: The link you gave seems pretty clear to me, what is bothering you?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: i do not have any problem with the link. It was just additional information. Please check the edit.

Comment: Experimentation with a few numbers will show that one cannot deduce anything useful.

Comment: No. Insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing you can do is invoke the triangle inequality, i.e. $|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|$. Note that this equality works for *negative* $x$, $y$ as well. This gives you $$
\begin{eqnarray}
|k_1 - k_2| &\leq& |k_1| + |k_2| &\leq |a| + |b| \text{ and since }k_1-k_2 \leq |k_1-k_2| \\
k_1 - k_2 &\leq& |k_1| + |k_2|  &\leq |a| + |b|
\end{eqnarray}
$$

For arbitrary $k_1 \leq a$, $k_2 \leq b$, you can't do better than that, but since you stated that $k_1,k_2 \geq 0$, you can. $k_1,k_2$ being positive means that $$
\begin{eqnarray}
-b &\leq& -k_2 &\leq& k_1 - k_2 &\leq& k_1 &\leq& a\\
-a &\leq& -k_1 &\leq& k_2 - k_1 &\leq& k_2 &\leq& b
\end{eqnarray}
$$
because subtracting a positive number can only make a number smaller, never bigger.

Comment: In your first derivation, how can you bound $k_1 -k_2$ by $|a| + |b|$ simply given $k_1 \leq a$ and $k_2 \leq b$? What if $k_2\to-\infty$?

Comment: @jjjjjj The question states that "$k_1$, $k_2$, $a$, $b$ are all positive numbers"

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at some example. We know that
$$
4<8, 2<10,
$$
but we don't have $4-2<8-10$. On the other hand, $$ 3<9,4<8$$ 
but you cannot say $3-4>9-8$. There is nothing to deduce from substrating inequalities that are of the same side

Comment: No, but you can say that $2 = 4-2 \leq \text{max}\{8,10\} = 10$

Comment: I could say $6<10, -8<9$ but now $14=6-(-8)\leq\max\{9,10\}=10$ does not hold. I know that $-8-6$ would hold, just saying

Comment: According to the question, $k_1,k_2 \geq 0$.

Comment: oh you're right, but then this becomes a trivial bound :)

Comment: Still better than no bound ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate proof that you cannot say anything about it:

Suppose you would be able to find that $k_1-k_2\leq f(a,b)$ holds for some $f$, and $f(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $k_2\geq k_1-f(a,b)$. And because $k_2\leq b$ we have $k_1-f(a,b)\leq b$.

However, we can substitute $k_2=x=k_1-f(a,b)-1$. This value is allowed since $x\leq b$. But $x$ does not satisfy the condition $x\geq k_1-f(a,b)$.

That means that $f(a,b)\not\in\mathbb{R}$, so $f(a,b)=\infty$

It may look like an otiose proof, but i don't think it is.

Comment: $k_1 - k_2 \leq |k_1| + |k_2| \leq |a| + |b| = f(a,b)$ is a counter-example to your "proof".

Comment: Yes it is, but i don't see where the 'proof' goes wrong...

Comment: Dunno, but the second part looks pretty confused to me. What is $x$? And into *which* term are you substituting *what* value?

Comment: I let $k_2$ be $k_1-f(a,b)-1$. (I just used $x$ as an other name for it.)

Answer (score 0):

- Note that your property of summing inequalities for positive numbers can immediately be extended to signed numbers.

Indeed assuming $\begin{cases} k_1\le a\\k_2\le b\end{cases}$ then we have $\begin{cases} a-k_1\ge 0\\b-k_2\ge 0\end{cases}$ which are positive numbers.

Their sum is then positive $(a-k_1)+(b-k_2)\ge 0\iff (a+b)-(k_1+k_2)\ge 0$

Once rearranged it gives $$k_1+k_2\le a+b$$ independently of the signs of 
$a,b,k_1,k_2$

- Now the inequalities $\begin{cases} k_1\le a\\k_2\le b\end{cases}$  with positive numbers are in fact $\begin{cases} 0\le k_1\le a\\0\le k_2\le b\end{cases}$

We can invert the first one to get $\begin{cases} -a\le -k_1\le 0\\0\le k_2\le b\end{cases}$

Now summing all inequalities like we have seen in first point gives: $-a+0\le -k_1+k_2\le b+0$

Or simply $$-a\le k_2-k_1\le b$$

Answer (score -1):

### Finding the inequality with k(1) - K(2) as the subject

The simplest solution is usually the best solution----Albert Einstein

**Given:**

k(1) ≤ a

k(2) ≤ b

**Required:** To determine if  k(1) - K(2) can be made the subject of an inequality

```
       derived from the above inequalities
```

**Possible solution:**

One will operate on the given system of inequalities.

Generally, subtracting c < d from a < b yields a - d < b - c; but below, one

will apply the permissible operations on a system of inequalities. To add a

system of two inequalities, both inequalities must have the same sense (or

direction). To subtract an inequality, multiply this "subtrahend"  inequality by

-1 while reversing the sense of the inequality, and then add to the "minuend

inequality", making sure the two inequalities have the same sense.

**Now**,  one will subtract K(2) ≤ b from k(1) ≤ a).

**Step 1:** Multiply the "subtrahend" inequality,  K(2) ≤ b  by -1 and reverse the

```
     sense to obtain - K(2) ≥ - b......(1)
```

**Step 2:** Rewrite (1) so that it has the same sense as the "minuend" inequality,

```
    k(1) ≤ a. Then one obtains -b ≤ -k(2)
```

**Step 3** Add the left sides and add the right sides below

```
   k(1) ≤ a
     -b ≤ -K(2)
 ---------------
```

k(1) - b ≤ a - k(2)  <-----the "difference" inequality,

From the above result, k(1) - k(2) cannot be made the subject of the above

inequality.

**Conclusion:**

Therefore, explicitly, k(1) - k(2) **does not exist.**

However, implicitly, k(1) - k(2) ≤ a + b - **2**k(2)

**Repeating the above procedure**, using a, b, c, d

**Given**

a ≤ b...........(1).

c ≤ d............(2);

determine if a - c can be made the subject of the inequality derived from 
the above system of inequalities.

**Solution**

From (2)  -c ≥ -d         (multiplying by -1 in order to subtract)

```
     -d ≤ -c....(3) (rewriting in the same sense as (1))
```

Adding the left sides of (1) and (3); and adding the right sides of (1) and (3),

one obtains

a - d ≤ b - c...........(4)

**Conclusion**

Explicitly, in (4), a - c cannot be made the subject of (4),

However, implicitly, a - c ≤ b + d - 2c

Comment: [mathjax references](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). Also, it would be great to answer in terms of algebra for generality.

Answer (score -1):

First, recall that you can express your problem statement in terms of the set of inequalities

$0<k_1 \leq a$ and $0<k_2\leq b$.

This naturally leads naturally to $$-b<k_1-k_2 <a.$$ Here I would like to stress that the set of strict inequalities follows from the fact that $k_1>0$ and $-k_2<0$.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an alternative strategy based on the identity $|k_1-k_2|=\sqrt{(k_1-k_2)^2}.$

First of all, we use the fact that $k_1,k_2>0$, $k_1\leq a$ and $k_1\leq b$ to show that

$$(k_1-k_2)^2=k_1^2+k_2^2-2k_1k_2<a^2+b^2,$$
and hence, the strict inequality
$$ |k_1-k_2|<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

In comparison with the inequality that I've derived previously ($-b<k_1-k_2<a$), this approach gives rise to a rough estimation for the upper and lower bounds of $k_1-k_2$.